# Intercept specific URL in the network tab (headless) and open it using Playwright and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, playwright

What i'm trying to achieve is some automation using playwright: i need to open a web page (in my case a router http server), log in into it and monitor the network tab for a specific URL. When this URL become available i need to open it and print the page to the log. This is my code so far:

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: true })
  const context = await browser.newContext()
  const page = await context.newPage()
    
   await page.route('**/ajax/internet.lua', async (route,request) => {
   await page.goto (request.url())});
    
  await page.goto('http://router-ip')
  
  await page.setViewportSize({ width: 1242, height: 568 })
  
  await page.waitForSelector('#login #srp_password')
  await page.click('#login #srp_password')
  await page.keyboard.type('password')
  
  await page.waitForSelector('#login #sign-me-in')
  await page.click('#login #sign-me-in')
  
  await page.waitForNavigation()
  await browser.close()
  
 

})()
```

With this code i can login successfully and monitor the network log for the URL i need but when i try to open it i receive an endless loop of errors until i force close the script:

```
(node:6708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: page.goto: net::ERR_ABORTED at http://router-ip/ajax/internet.lua
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "http://router-ip/ajax/internet.lua", waiting until "load"
============================================================

(node:6708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6708) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I really don't know how to fix and continue so any help is really appreciated, thank you very much.

UPDATE:

Finally, this is the code which seems to work without the need to go to the URL: with this i'll get the page response directly printed in the console.log:

```
page.on('response', async response => {
   if (response.url().includes("/ajax/internet.lua")) {
   resp = await response.json()
   await page.evaluate(() => window.stop())
   console.log(resp)
    }
  })
```